# How to find past editors and editorial board members of scientific journals?

Tags: journals, editors, data, open-science

Journal websites usually list their *present* editors and editorial board members.

Is there any systematic way to find out the journals' *past* editors and editorial board members (if possible, in a large-scale and machine-readable manner)?

Comment: Usually there is some listing, either annually or in each volume. Check the journal archives.

Comment: Although I see the problem now - it depends on the journal. Calphad has an 'article' in each issue with the board, Applied Physics Letters does not make their listing available electronically.

Comment: What would one need this kind of information for? Data is generally only collected and made available in a machine-readable manner if people see a purpose in this. But I can't see a purpose.

Comment: I thought each issue/volume would have a page (1st page) that lists the editorial board at the time of that particular issue/volume.

Comment: If you have a current affiliation with a university, have you tried asking the reference librarian this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the journal's past issues, which will usually come with a page that says who the editorial board members are. If you can't find it online, get it from a print copy.